# In which cases should I split the data in training set and test set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, regularization, overfitting, ridge-regression

I am taking a course on machine learning and in one problem I should perform a Ridge regression to fit some given data to a known model. I was wondering if, in this case, there are any advantage in splitting the data into training set and test set. At the end of the day I am performing Ridge regression on a known model, hence there is no risk of overfitting. Is there any other reason to split the data in such way?

Comment: Why do you say there is no risk of overfitting?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I assume it since I know the model that generates the data.

Comment: How does your knowledge of the data generating process enter into the ridge regression? Ridge regression alone can also overfit.

Comment: Because it was given in the statement of the problem.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is meant by "known model". Known to whom? Why does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Your evaluation should always be performed on a holdout set. In the simplest setups, this reduces to train & test sets. So, you should split. Ridge regression has regularisation mechanics but it may not save you from overfitting.